# efficient way for finding min value on each given region

Tags: performance, algorithm, optimization, hash, matrix

Given a
[image]
we first define two real-valued functions [image] and [image] as follows:

[image]
[image]

and we also define a value `m(X)` for each matrix `X` as follows:
[image]

Now given an [image], we have many regions of `G`, denoted as [image]. Here, a region of `G` is formed by a submatrix of `G` that is randomly chosen from some columns and some rows of `G`. And our problem is to compute [image] as fewer operations as possible. Is there any methods like building hash table, or sorting to get the results faster? Thanks!

========================

For example, if `G={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}`, then

```
G_1 could be {{1,2},{7,8}}
G_2 could be {{1,3},{4,6},{7,9}}
G_3 could be {{5,6},{8,9}}
```

=======================

Currently, for each `G_i` we need mxn comparisons to compute `m(G_i)`. Thus, for `m(G_1),...,m(G_r)` there should be rxmxn comparisons. However, I can notice that `G_i` and `G_j` maybe overlapped, so there would be some other approach that is more effective. Any attention would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Edit your question for readability or we won't read it.

Comment: There's no support for LaTeX and similar on Stackoverflow, you should reformat your question ;) [I wish this was different.. MathJax support on math.stackexchange is very nice]

Comment: I edited it for him.

Comment: Thanks, David. Having submitted, I just realized it..

Comment: How are `G`s represented? Given `Gi`, is it directly obvious which rows and which columns of `X` it has? For example, does the representation of `Gi` say: "`Gi` is rows 2, 5, 7 and columns 1, 6 of X"?

Comment: @David: Too bad you can't get reputation for amazing edits like this. Really helps the community.

Comment: So the real question is, why can't we have the same features here that math.stackexchange has?

Comment: @MrLister: I'd say: time to ask on meta :)

Comment: Yeah, I did wonder myself if my question wouldn't be better off on Meta.

Comment: @Shahbaz, yeah. I've provided more examples in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how many times the min/max type data is needed, you could consider a matrix that holds min/max information in-between the matrix values, i.e. in the interstices between values..  Thus, for your example G={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}} we  would define a relationship matrix R sized ((mxn),(mxn),(mxn)) and having values from the set C = {-1 = less than, 0 = equals and 1 = greater than}.

R would have nine relationship pairs (n,1), (n,2) to (n,9) where each value would be a member of C.  Note (n,n is defined and will equal 0).  Thus,  R[4,,) = (1,1,1,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1).  Now consider any of your subsets G_1 ...,  Knowing the positional relationships of a subset's members will give you offsets into R which will resolve to indexes into each R(N,,) which will return the desired relationship information directly without comparisons.

You, of course, will have to decide if the overhead in space and calculations to build R exceeds the cost of just computing what you need each time it's needed.  Certain optimizations including realization that the R matrix is reflected along the major diagonal and that you could declare "equals" to be called, say, less than (meaning C has only two values) are available.  Depending on the original matrix G, other optimizations can be had if it is know that a row or column is sorted.

And since some computers (mainframes, supercomputers, etc) store data into RAM in column-major order, store your dataset so that it fills in with the rows and columns transposed thus allowing column-to-column type operations (vector calculations) to actually favor the columns.  Check your architecture.

Comment: One last thought, C++ for this kind of math?  Isn't this more a modern, vectorized, pipeline FORTRAN problem?

Comment: @ Wes Miller, Is there a reference for modern, vectorized, pipeline FORTRAN problem?

Comment: Sadly, @JohnSmith This is a fragment of a memory from a grad course of 1684 when Cray and CDC were selling like gangbusters. I suspect there are still such machines out there, but I haven't really looked for them.